# Find the min/max/average etc. of a range of cells that varies in length?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to find something like the min/max/average etc. of a range of cells within a spreadsheet, when I don't know the end of the range.

**Within my macro I use the following:**

```vb
Raw1.Range("H4").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Sheets("Raw").Range("A3"), Sheets("Raw").Range("A3").End(xlDown)))
```

I would like to use different than this, because this gives "one of value" each time the code is run.

I want the value of H4 to change each time the values of A3 changes without having to run the macro. So more like a formula.

Something like:

```vb
Raw1.Range("H3").Value = "= Min((A3:A & Range.End(xlDown).Row))"
```

Comment: `=MIN(A:A)` perhaps?

Comment: Or if you have numbers in A1 and A2: `=MIN(A3:A1040000)`

Comment: I did think about the A3:A1000000) method but thought maybe there was something that would be a bit more precise...

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want actively to have to run a macro, the suggestion below is coded in the `Worksheet_Change()` [event procedure](https://youtu.be./0EXdPcbsTZI&t=1557s):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        Dim lastCell As Long, pos As Long, formulaCell As Range
        Set formulaCell = Range("H4")
        lastCell = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        pos = InStr(1, formulaCell.Formula, "(") - 1
        formulaCell.Formula = Left(formulaCell.Formula, pos) & "(A2:A" & lastCell & ")"
    End If
End Sub
```

it is premised on the examples in your OP, in that the cell in question contains a *simple* formula (i.e. the address of the referenced cells comes after the 1st `(` of the existing formula, and there is nothing, other than the `)` after this reference), the range reference for which the event procedure will update whenever a change in column A is detected.